# MathML to Image (like JEuclid) that works on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, apache-fop, mathml

I was wondering if somebody succeeded in transforming from MathML expressions into images in GAE.

GAE imposes many limitations on the classes allowed (bye bye FOP/ JEUclid) and I cannot do the logic in the front-end (mathjax) since the target is to print a pdf.

So far I contemplate either changing PaaS or switching to managed vm in GAE but it seems rather overkill.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have such experience, with processing math formulas and generating a PDF. It took a time, but I managed to do that on Appengine. I tried most of know libraries, including FOP, none of them works on gae, of course.

What I'm using:

- [mathtex.cgi](http://www.forkosh.com/mathtex.html) for math render. It can generate an image through HTTP call, just pass formula in request, and get a PNG. I've installed on separate server (I already had this server, very basic one, for wordpress and stuff, so that was not a problem). Also you could find few public servers with mathtex.cgi, including official one, that you can use w/o having own server
- [appengine-itext](https://github.com/bedatadriven/appengine-export) for PDF. It have some minor issues, but mostly works. To put formulas into PDF I've following hack: a simple regex replaces math code with a `<img>` tag that points to a dummy protocol `math://`, then I have a custom `ImageProvider` that renders formula by using MathTex for such urls
- for browser clients MathJax works fine

Little bit hacky, and requires a cheap external server, but that works

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I am using itextpdf and that works fine for PDF generation on GAE but the JEUclid for MathML does not.

Yes, calling an external system (e.g. mathmlcloud) to get the image was something I had in mind but it is...hacky.

Comment: yes, hacky, but it's only way. i spent almost a month (ok, parttime, but anyway) trying different options, until it developed into this